# Oracle SQL Developer - how to view listing of OLAP script instead of executing?

Tags: sql, oracle, olap

In Oracle SQL Developer, my database connection is to an Oracle server at uni, where my database is hosted.
The code I have to run a marking script, to assess my stored procedures  for an assignment, is:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Clear screen ;
EXECUTE johnSmith.mark_ass1;
show errors;
```

I want to see inside johnSmith.mark_ass1 instead of just executing it.
This script is insisting that my stored procs are wrong, I'd like to know why as I'm quite sure this is not the case (at least according to the assignment specs I was given)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the procedure source code, in the `all_source` view?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I am on the right track now. 
In Oracle SQL Developer I have gone to the "View\Find DB Object" option.
In the panel that appears I can check a box (for things that will be searched) for "Code", under that "All Source Lines", "All Views".... and in the schema's I can select johnSmith, in addition to my own. It looks like I can see parts of his scripts, I will do some more digging now. 
Thanks again